# How to forward one domain in nginx to different subdirectories (php, rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I own a VPS server for development which runs on Ubuntu server 14.04 x64 LTS. I have some RoR sites and some Wordpress ones. I want to be able to play with them by git pushing them to separate directories.
That means that I should have a rails website in xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/myrailsweb and another wordpress website in xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mywpweb. How do I achieve this with server blocks in nginx ?

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    location /apps/testphp {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

and

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  # server_name 127.0.0.1;
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env development;
  root /home/myname/apps/testapp/public;
}
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have them on different ports.  So 127.0.0.1:3000 go to the rails site and 127.0.0.1 goes to wordpress or something like that.  So using your example:

```
server {
  listen 3000;
  server_name 127.0.0.1;
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env development;
  root /home/myname/apps/testapp/public;
}
```

On a live server then just use subdomains.

Comment: It's a quite nice idea (works, I tested it), but it doesn't fullfill my purpose. I will follow this way If I don't have any other choices because unfortunately it makes things more complicated by having to remember ports and doesn't have the /nameofmywebsite/ to the path after the ip address.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to use `/nameofmywebsite` to be honest.  I don't think it would work in rails, might do in wordpress but again I'd doubt it.  Slightly mental imo but you could have redirects to the correct port based on the `/nameofmywebsite`